# Combining multiple estimators in SKlearn for multilabel multiclass

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

I have been researching ensemble methods in sklearn: [sklearn ensemble](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#forest). I am trying to train several different estimators and combine the results, as in example 1.11.5.1 (near the bottom of the page, VotingClassifier). However, my problem is multiclass multilabel and this is not supported.

How can I combine the results from multiple different types of estimator, in order to classify multiclass multilabel data?

I have tried outputting probabilities for each label and then averaging, but the results are worse than the individual models. Thanks.

Comment: You could try a product-of-experts: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_of_experts